# How can i solve a forbidden error connecting to azure delta lake?

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am creating a software to access to protected data on azure delta lake. Before accessing the data, i need to ask access through a specific company portal. If i ask access and then try to query, everything works well. When i forget to ask for, i am  obviously blocked by a 403 http error. But then, even after i get permissions, i am not able to load the data from my python software until a time T is passed (usually, T is about 45 mins).

I don't understand this behavior, since if i try the same procedure through databricks it works perfectly once i restart my current running cluster.

with polars library in python i am doing:

```
pl.scan_delta(path, storage_options=options)
```

where

```
options = {"AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME": storage_account_name,"AZURE_USE_AZURE_CLI": 'true' }
```

but if i forget to ask for data access, i get

```
OSError: Generic MicrosoftAzure error: response error "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
```

even after i ask for it

Comment: provide more details on it.

Comment: with polars library in python i am doing:

`pl.scan_delta(path, storage_options=options)`
where
`options = {
    "AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME": storage_account_name,
    "AZURE_USE_AZURE_CLI": 'true'
}`

but if i forget to ask for data access, i get

`OSError: Generic MicrosoftAzure error: response error "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.`
even after i ask for it

Comment: After 45 mins you can able to access right?

Comment: 45 min is just an estimation, in general after T minutes

Comment: How are you getting access? Once you done `az login` that should work.

Comment: i already have logged in.  the problem is that data i need needs some more permission approval from my company.

Answer (score 0):

> OSError: Generic MicrosoftAzure error: response error " version="1.0"> encoding="utf-8"?>`AuthorizationPermissionMismatch`This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

The above error when a user or principal doesn't have the proper role or permission to access the resource.

For accessing, Azure blob storage you need to assign **[Storage-blob-data-contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-contributor)** role to your storage account.

**Portal:**

[image]

After assigning the role, signed in with **`az login`** to authenticate with the user and tried with the below code it executed successfully.

**Code:**

```
import polars as pl
 
options = {"AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME": "<Storage account name>","AZURE_USE_AZURE_CLI": 'true' }
table_path = "az://<conatiner name>/path/to/delta-table/"
print(pl.scan_delta(table_path, storage_options=options).collect())
```

**Output:**

```
shape: (12, 1)
┌─────────────────────┐
│ epoch_milliseconds  │
│ ---                 │
│ i64                 │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 9223372036854775807 │
│ 1614848999014       │
│ 1620035396699       │
│ 9223372036854775807 │
│ …                   │
│ 1620035396699       │
│ 9223372036854775807 │
│ null                │
│ 1620035396699       │
└─────────────────────┘
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[polars.scan_delta — Polars documentation (pola-rs.github.io)](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_delta.html)

Comment: thank you for the answer. by the way, i already did all thew steps you mentioned. the problem is that, once everything is configured, i need to ask through a company portal a temporary additional permission to get access to the data.
If i do it through the portal everything works, but if i forget to ask the permission and try to access, i get blocked (as expected). 
The problem is that if i ask for the permissions AFTER trying to access, i am able to access the data only after about 45 minutes (without doing anything else)

Comment: I think they added the role after 45 minutes.

Comment: @Venkatesan it looks strange, since if i do not forget to ask permissions before trying to connect, it works immediately.

Comment: If you are using cli credential with user you need `storage blob data contributor`  role to acess the blob data.

Comment: Try az logout and again try `az login` it will work fine.